# Method based validation using Spring validator interface

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator, spring-restcontroller

I am developing a service using Spring. As a part of it, I have a controller class which deals with one particular object(Let us assume it is Obj1). I have 3 methods in the controller class.

1. One method to fetch all Obj1s from database(needs no validation).
2. One method to save a new Obj1 to the database (In this case the ID field in Obj1 should be 0).
3. One more method to update an existing Obj1(In this case the ID field should be greater than 0).

I have a class that implements **validator** interface. I use this class to perform all the validations.Let us call it Obj1Validator.

How can I perform validation based on the controller method called in the class that implements validator interface?

I know that I can **annotate** the object properties and use **groups** and **validated** annotation to perform this kind of validation instead of doing it using **validator** interface. Or I can use partial annotation and partial validator approach.

However, I have tried to explain my validation requirement using a simple scenario though in reality the validation I need to perform is much more complex and hence I have to use Validator interface and not the annotation based validation.

Can some one tell me how can I handle this scenario? Or is there any way to get the group mentioned in **@validated(group="x")** inside **Obj1Validator**, in which case I can easily perform method based validation.